# PowerBuilder application - Debug

Tags: powerbuilder

In PowerBuilder application, How can I get the time:minute:seconds details which function executes with in (hh:mm:ss) time and which looping statement taking more time to execute?

Is there and command like PBDEBUG?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make some profiling on your code

1 - go to `System Options` / `Profiling`, check `Enable Tracing` and enter the path of a non existing file in `Trace file Name`. Also, select the trace activities that you want to survey.

2 - start your application and do the task that you want to analyze

3 - stop your program

4 - in Powerbuilder, `File` / `New...` / `Tool` and select one of the profiling viewers, between `Profiling class view`, `Profiling  routine view` or `Profiling trace view`, depending on the type of analyze.

Usualy, I get some useful timing information with the Trace view : times and hit counts.

Answer (score 1):

To instrument a particular piece of code you can use the `cpu` function to get the processor time before and after a section of code. If you're using PFC you can put the data in the debug log. If you aren't using PFC you could write the data to a file. This is useful enough that we've added performance monitoring to our framework.

Answer (score 0):

For Powerbuiler, ThickGrid provides the best solution to trace your events functions and SQLs together. I found it easy. you may checkout www.thickgrid.com, they will help you to integrate the feature.